# Radio button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails (and non ASP.NET web development). For creating a user signup page with a radio button, I'm doing the following. However the user.roles is not updated. What could be the problem? 
(I edited the user model created by sorcery gem to add a new string field `roles`.)

view/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
     ..
    <div class="field">
        <%= radio_button_tag(:assistanttype, "TA") %>
        <%= label_tag("TA") %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:assistanttype, "RA") %>
        <%= label_tag("RA") %>  
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
 ..
<div class="field">
    <% %w{TA RA}.each do |value|-%>
    <% f.radio_button :assistanttype, value %> <% value %><br />
    <% end -%> 
  </div>
```

%w{} is used to put string inside and automatically change it to an array. 
Example:
%w{A B C} = [A, B, C]

Comment: im sorry the <%end %> was part of an if, i forgot to add here.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Comment: It should be %w{} not  w%{}. Sorry my bad.